# How to anchor unity game object to the corner of a cameras view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I need to anchor a game object to the corner of a cameras view, regardless of that objects size. I need to do this because I am making UI without unity's built in system (the built in one messes with my pixel art).

Here's the code I've come up with thus far:
`
public class BuildingMenuScalePos : MonoBehaviour
{
private Transform myTransform;

```
int screenX;
int screenY;
int offSet;

float prevCamScale;
float camScale;

Vector2 screenSize;
Vector2 prevScreenSize;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    prevCamScale = Camera.main.orthographicSize;
    myTransform = GetComponent<Transform>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    // Updates anchor posisiton when camera scale or screen size changess
    // Important because pixel perfect camera changes orthographic size at the start
    camScale = Camera.main.orthographicSize;
    screenSize = new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height);
    offSet = ((Screen.height / 180) / 2) * 8;

    if (camScale != prevCamScale || screenSize != prevScreenSize)
    {
        myTransform.localScale = new Vector3(8.5f, (float)Screen.height / (offSet * 2), 1);
        setUIToAnchor(2, -offSet * (float)myTransform.lossyScale.x, -offSet * (float)myTransform.lossyScale.y);
        prevCamScale = camScale;
        prevScreenSize = screenSize;
        
    }
}

// Moves object to anchor point
void setUIToAnchor(int anchorPos, float offSetX, float offSetY)
{
    Vector3 UIWorldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(setAnchor(anchorPos, offSetX, offSetY)); // Converts from pixels to world space
    myTransform.position = UIWorldPos;
}

// Sets object anchor position on screen (in pixels)
Vector3 setAnchor(int anchorPos, float offSetX, float offSetY)
{

    switch (anchorPos)
    {
        case 0: // Bottom Left
            screenX = 0;
            screenY = 0;
            break;

        case 1: // Top Left
            screenX = 0;
            screenY = Screen.height;
            break;

        case 2: // Top Right
            screenX = Screen.width;
            screenY = Screen.height;
            break;

        case 3: // Bottom Right
            screenX = Screen.width;
            screenY = 0;
            break;

        case 4: // Left side middle
            screenX = 0;
            screenY = Screen.height / 2;
            break;

        case 5: // Up side middle
            screenX = Screen.width / 2;
            screenY = Screen.height;
            break;

        case 6: // Right side middle
            screenX = Screen.width;
            screenY = Screen.height / 2;
            break;

        case 7: // Down side middle
            screenX = Screen.width / 2;
            screenY = 0;
            break;

        case 8: // Center
            screenX = Screen.width / 2;
            screenY = Screen.height / 2;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return new Vector3(screenX + offSetX, screenY + offSetY, 1);
}
```

}
`

This code gets anchor position in pixels, then converts that number into world space units. Afterwards it just places my UI game object at those world space coordinates.

The code works, but only using Free aspect, 4:3, 16:9, etc. If I use a set resolution like 1920x1080 the box is no longer placed in the corner of the screen correctly. The offset seems to cause this behavior, because if I set it to 0 the middle of the UI sprite is placed perfectly in the corner regardless of res or aspect ratio. Set resolution also seem to break the pixel perfect camera, because my sprites become blurry.

[Screenshot examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBtrJ.jpg)

I just want to know why free aspect ratios and fixed res are different. And I'd appreciate if someone knows how to make pixel perfect UI, that's maybe a more elegant solution than what I'm doing.

Comment: `If I use a set resolution like 1920x1080 the box is no longer placed in the corner of the screen correctly` that's probably because you only do things `if (camScale != prevCamScale || screenSize != prevScreenSize)` which pobably doesn't change once you have set a fixed resolution ..

Comment: in general: If your object is 8 x 8 .. wouldn't it then rather need to be `-8 * myTransform.lossyScale.x * 0.5f`? First I would use the absolute lossyScale and then half of it since the center should be at `topright - (4, 4)`

Comment: I tried `-8 * myTransform.lossyScale.x * 0.5f` But it only moves it half as much as it needs to. I know from the center to the outer corners it should only be 4 pixels, but it's not. Also I wrote some new code which seems to work. But I have to change the offset according to resolution? Yeah really weird but it works for all the aspect ratios, and resolutions which are a multiple of my pixel perfect camera reference resolution (320 * 180)